# How to move all referenced DLLs into seperate folder in c#?

Tags: c#, setup-project

I have a solution with 3 projects in it. 2 of the projects are referencing log4net, and a couple of others DLLs.

When I create the install package and add project output for each of the projects - it drops the DLLs into the main "Application Folder". If I drag these DLLs into a seperate folder I've created in the Setup Project, the applications will not run saying "Cannot find log4net". I want these DLL references in something like "bin" or any name really, just not the main folder they add confusion - I just want my 2 .exe's in the main folder.

I tried adding a reference path in each project to point to the "bin" folder. Then in the setup project, I added an output folder called "bin" and moved the DLLs into that folder, still doesn't work.

What am I missing! I've spent a couple hours looking around trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, maybe it was the way I was born! Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`<probing>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx) in the app.config file to specify a private path for Fusion (the assembly loader) to search in.

This allows you to specify paths that are sub-paths of your application directory which Fusion should search when trying to find assemblies to bind to.  An example (taken from the documentation page) is:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This means that Fusion will search in the bin, bin2\subbin (but not bin2, IIRC) and bin3 subdirectories for assemblies when trying to bind to them.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a nuget package, called [PrettyBin](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PrettyBin/) for this purpose
It addes a post build target to a project, that moves dlls to a "lib" subfolder, and modifies app.config to look there