# How to move third party dlls from bin folder to another folder in ASP.NET Web Forms project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, webforms, bin-folder

There are some third party dlls in Bin folder. I would like to move them to root/lib path. I think, it is not enough move the files to lib folder. How can i do this, safely? These are dlls;

- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
- Newtonsoft.Json.dll
- NReco.PdfGenerator
- System.Web.Optimization.dll
- WebGrease.dll

**Update:** I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996358/how-to-move-all-referenced-dlls-into-seperate-folder-in-c][1]) and i got an error like; *The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'*

The error occurred on this line: `using System.Web.Optimization;`

I created a new lib folder on root directory, moved System.Web.Optimization.dll file to lib. Then, i edited my web.config as below;

```
    <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <probing privatePath="bin;lib"/>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13263992/6431655). So, if you want to move third party dlls to new folder, you can follow these steps;

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="Bin;folder_path"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

1. Create a new folder to move dlls
2. Update web.config like above
3. Add moved assemblies between system.web tags

   ```
   <add assembly="System.Web.Optimization" />
   <add assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can check with the link below.

[How to move all referenced DLLs into seperate folder in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996358/how-to-move-all-referenced-dlls-into-seperate-folder-in-c][1])

Hope this helps!