# How can i Arrange app dll files in dot net Core

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

I built an application in dotnet core 3.1
and after build i see in bin folder Lots of dlls and xmls
here screen shot
[image: dll hell]

And I want it to look like this
[image]

someone can please help me :-((((

Comment: You have 2 answers under this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996358/how-to-move-all-referenced-dlls-into-seperate-folder-in-c

Comment: @Adriani6 I think he wanted to structurize his output, not just change output folder path. Or I am missing something?

Comment: @BlueCompany No, I missed the exe in the root directory on the screenshot, good spot though :)

Comment: BlueCompany  -- i tried this 2 but i have dot net core not dot net framework so my app work with out app.config and  PrettyBin  not working

Comment: Found another source: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Apr/30/NET-Core-30-SDK-Projects-Controlling-Output-Folders-and-Content but is to late for me to test it. Nice question tho.

Comment: (a) I would strongly suggest not messing with it and adding another layer of possible issues.  (my opinion)....but (b)  consider this :: dotnet publish /p:PublishSingleFile=true for your released code

Answer (score 2):

In .net framework you can use `AssemblyBinding probing` in app.exe.config and use `Post Build Events Command Line` in Visual Studio to move your dll and xml in the custom folder.

In .net core 3.1 `additionalProbingPaths` seems doesn't work fine but you can still use `Post Build Events Command Line` to move your xml in the custom folder.

*Note:
1. `AssemblyBinding probing` and `additionalProbingPaths` will affect your assembly load dll location.
2. If you don't know `Post Build Events Command Line` see [the guide line](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/prepost-build-events-command-line-in-visual-studio/).*

See the below issues about probing path.
[Additional probing paths for .NET Core 3 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844233/additional-probing-paths-for-net-core-3-migration)
[donet/sdk issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10366).

Finally I found [nulastudio.NetCoreBeauty](https://github.com/nulastudio/NetCoreBeauty) library which seems like you want feature.